SOAP namespaces missing after upgrade from php7.4 to php8.1
When sending SOAP on php7.4 we had nicely namespaced elements, like this:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:ns1="http://blah/Schemas/CommonTypes_v1.0"
 xmlns:ns2="http://blah/Schemas/XDRS_v1.0">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns2:XRSRequest>
    <ns2:XRSDetails>
      <ns2:XDetails>
        <ns2:XName>
          <ns1:XFamilyName>Cambridge</ns1:XFamilyName>

after the upgrade, we got stuck with this:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <XRSRequest>
    <XRSDetails>
      <XDetails>
        <XName>
          <XFamilyName>Cambridge</XFamilyName>

The two required namespaces are declared in the WSDL file which has not changed. I don't know why they are no longer being applied... any help would be appreciated!
Oh and the SOAP generator was WsdltoPhp/PackageGenerator
